# Phantom js with React js cannot find less js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, less, reactjs

I am trying to unit test a react project based on the unit testing frameworks used in this

https://github.com/pheuter/essential-react

The unit testing for my project is setup exactly like this one. My problem is it does not seem to support less js files. Every time I try to run a test a file that has less in it I receive this error from phantom js

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: Cannot find module "./Dashboard.less"
  at /Unit_Tests/main.js:26577

My main.js file look

```
/**
 * Test suite entry point
 */

// Babel Polyfill
import 'babel-core/polyfill';

import './routes/Home_Test';
//import './routes/Dashboard.less';
```

and my karma.config.js

```
/**
 * This is the Karma configuration file. It contains information about this skeleton
 * that provides the test runner with instructions on how to run the tests and
 * generate the code coverage report.
 *
 * For more info, see: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html
 */
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    /**
     * These are the files required to run the tests.
     *
     * The `Function.prototype.bind` polyfill is required by PhantomJS
     * because it uses an older version of JavaScript.
     */
    files: [
      './Unit_Tests/polyfill.js',
      './Unit_Tests/main.js'
    ],

    /**
     * The actual tests are preprocessed by the karma-webpack plugin, so that
     * their source can be properly transpiled.
     */
    preprocessors: {
      './Unit_Tests/main.js': ['webpack']
    },

    /**
     * We want to run the tests using the PhantomJS headless browser.
     * This is especially useful for continuous integration.
     */
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    /**
     * Use Mocha as the test framework, Sinon for mocking, and
     * Chai for assertions.
     */
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'sinon-chai'],

    /**
     * After running the tests, return the results and generate a
     * code coverage report.
     */
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

    /**
     * When generating a code coverage report, use `lcov` format and
     * place the result in coverage/lcov.info
     *
     * This file will be sent to Coveralls by the `coveralls` npm script.
     */
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: 'coverage/',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'lcovonly', subdir: '.', file: 'lcov.info' },
        { type: 'html', subdir: 'html' }
      ]
    },

    /**
     * The configuration for the karma-webpack plugin.
     *
     * This is very similar to the main webpack.local.config.js, with the
     * exception of specifying an istanbul-transformer post loader so
     * that we can generate an accurate code coverage report.
     */
    webpack: {
      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader?stage=0"}
        ],
        postLoaders: [{
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /(test|node_modules)\//,
          loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter'
        }]
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
      }
    },

    /**
     * Configuration option to turn off verbose logging of webpack compilation.
     */
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    },

    /**
     * Once the mocha test suite returns, we want to exit from the test runner as well.
     */
    singleRun: true,

    /**
     * List of plugins
     */
    plugins: [
      'karma-mocha',
      'karma-webpack',
      'karma-coverage',
      'karma-sinon-chai',
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
    ],
  });
}
```

I have been looking around for a good answer on how to unit test files that contain less but cannot find one. I do not really care about unit testing the css just the jsx files.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out

```
    preprocessors: {
        './Unit_Tests/main.js': ['webpack'],
        '**/*.less': ['less']
    },

    webpack: {
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader?stage=0"},
                {test: /\.less$/, loader: "style!css!less"}
            ],
            postLoaders: [{
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(test|node_modules)\//,
                loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter'
            }]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.less']
        }
    },
```

Change your karma.config.js to include the following